# MS Access: Query to retrieve records that contains Text keywords stored in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In MS Access: From table X, listing all company names, I would like to select company names based upon the companynames in table Y. The company names in table Y are however representing a part of the name in table X.

> **Example:**
>
> **Table X**
>
> Company xyz bank
>
> xyz fund
>
> bankers xyz
>
> **Table Y;**
>
> xyz

I tried using the "Like" constraint and the Instr functions, but neither one seems to work. Can anyone of you help me?

Also see the lower link, which refers to my problem (except for that I am using Text data types)
[Link](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/find_keywords2007.php)

Comment: *I tried using the "Like" constraint and the Instr functions, but neither one seems to work* - Can you show us the code you tried? Actually, Like operator should work. Also provide table field names

Answer (score 2):

You can use `like` or `instr()`:

```
select . . .
from table1 as t1 inner join
     table2 as t2
     on t1.companyname like '*' & t2.col & '*';
```

I'm not 100% sure if that will work in MS Access, but this should:

```
select . . .
from table1 as t1 inner join
     table2 as t2
     on instr(t1.companyname, t2.col) > 0;
```

Comment: Assumes ANSI-89 Query Mode. Can be made query mode agnostic using `on t1.companyname alike '%' & t2.col & '%'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tablex.* 
FROM tableX,tableY 
WHERE tableX.col1 LIKE '*' + tableY.col1 + '*'
```

Comment: Should I write the "Where" part as a criteria in my query?

Comment: Yes...you need to

Answer (score 0):

Like should work for what you are doing. It may be that you did not write it quite right. It should be something like below:

```
select x.companyname
from x, y
where x.companyname like y.companyname
```

Comment: Should I write the "Where" part as a criteria in my query?